# extract a str contained between 2 str

Tags: python, string, split

Here is my problem :
considering a str of the form `[{val1:false, test2:0.1}, {val2:false, test2:0.2}, {val3:false, test2:0.1}, ....]`
I'd like to extract in a list of str the parts contained within "`{}`".

I tried :

```
re.findall(re.escape("{")+"(.*)"+re.escape("}"), "chosen str")
```

but this seems to be working only when one occurence of the "{"+...+"}" appears meaning in the present case this just returns a list of 1 str that is just like the entered form with the [{ got rid of both side.
To be clear I just would like the input proposed form to be collected in a list of the form `[["val1:false, test2:0.1"], [...]....]`

Any way to obtain that in a pythonic way?

Comment: I think `{(.+?)}` will do.

Comment: you want a list of strings in a list each?? Don't you mean obtaining ["val1:false, test2:0.1", "v2:1, v3:2", ...]?

Comment: If you don't need regex, you can use my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `.*` pattern nongreedy by using `.*?`.

For example,

```
In [44]: s
Out[44]: '{foo} {bar} {baz}'
```

Here's the "greedy" match:

```
In [45]: re.findall(re.escape("{")+"(.*)"+re.escape("}"), s)
Out[45]: ['foo} {bar} {baz']
```

Now the "nongreedy" match.  Note the added `?`:

```
In [46]: re.findall(re.escape("{")+"(.*?)"+re.escape("}"), s)
Out[46]: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy for more information about the distinction between greedy and nongreedy matching.

Comment: seems the "greedy" match is exactly what I need thanks

Comment: meant the "non greedy" one sorry

Answer (score 0):

It is not elegant but if you are sure to have a string exactly as you showed you can do:

```
s = "[{val1:false, test2:0.1}, {val2:false, test2:0.2}, {val3:false, test2:0.1}]"
s = s[1:-1] # remove leading "[" and ending "]"
l = [d + "}" for d in s.split("}, ")]
print l
```

The previous will generate:

```
['{val1:false, test2:0.1}', '{val2:false, test2:0.2}', '{val3:false, test2:0.1}}']
```

If you prefer a list of lists with strings (as said in your question), use:

```
l = [[d + "}"] for d in s.split("}, ")]
```

It will generate:

```
[['{val1:false, test2:0.1}'], ['{val2:false, test2:0.2}'], ['{val3:false, test2:0.1}}']]
```

Comment: I was planning on implementing a full code like yours unless I had the straight to the point function. THanks anyway for your help